# Call to promise then without defer

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

There is a way to call to this promises without the defer ?
I want to use **bluebird**

I want it to be called as promise chain with little timeout.

```
var step1 = function () {
    console.log("This is step 1, args=", arguments);
    return "ret 1";
};
var step2 = function () {
    console.log("This is step 2, args=", arguments);
    return "ret 2";
};

var deferred = Q.defer();
var promise0 = deferred.promise;
var promise1 = promise0.then(step1);
var promise2 = promise1.then(step2);

deferred.resolve("foo");
```

This is the jsFiddle which I use.

http://jsfiddle.net/HKhw8/1067/

**Update**

I need to add inside every then some logic but still display to the console the step 1,2,3 what am I doing wrong here?
http://jsfiddle.net/HKhw8/1073/

Comment: If all your actions are synchronous - do not use a promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Promise.resolve() // pass value you expect as argument in step1
    .then(step1)  // return value will be passed to step2 as argument
    .then(step2);
```

[`Promise.resolve`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.resolve.html) docs

Comment: Thanks Andrei , In case I need to add new logic inside every step(every then like timout) how you should do it?

Comment: you can simply update function body, but in case you don't want do this you can add additional steps between `.then(step1)`, `then(step2)`. I guess you're using promises as some kind of control flow? If there is no _asynchronous_ stuff inside your steps, there is no need for pormises

Comment: Thanks I use async control flow and this is just example to understand this better, when I use your suggestion I dont see the console output for steps what am I doing wrong http://jsfiddle.net/HKhw8/1071/

Comment: When promise resolved, callbacks passed to then methods called. I can see test1 and test2 in console, which is output of your anonymous functions  you've passed to then-s

Comment: Thanks but you dont see the stes

Comment: Quick note - check out this new js features to work with async stuff: [co](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co), [async/await](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99046/discussion-between-andrei-volchenko-and-mark).

Answer (score 0):

Bluebird specific answer.

```
Promise.try(step1).then(step2);
```

If you're using synchronous steps only - don't use promises.

Comment: HI Benjamin , Thanks but if I want to add addtional logic for example delay between the then and still see the steps console how would you do it ?

Comment: @Mark promises are very simple - they only work by `return` value - if you `return` a promise from a `then` it will wait for it before executing the next `then`.

Comment: Thanks can you please provide example how should I make it work http://jsfiddle.net/HKhw8/1073/

Comment: @Mark no, you learn - read stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises/ to understand how to create a version of `setTimeout` that returns promise. Then read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539815/arent-promises-just-callbacks to understand the chaining aspect. _after_ you've read both and wrote the code if it doesn't work I'll gladly help you with that :)